# My UIsearch bar does not work/send request to other sites

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode6

I'm still new to this but I'm confused on why my search bar does not work any time i put in a url address. I'm trying to make a video downloader app.

```
import UIKit
import AFNetworking
import Alamofire

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var Webview: UIWebView!
@IBOutlet var SearchBar: UISearchBar!

override func viewDidLoad() {


    if let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com"){

        let requestObj = URLRequest(url: url)

        Webview.loadRequest(requestObj)
    }
    SearchBar.text = "http://"

}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchbar: UISearchBar) {

    searchbar.resignFirstResponder()

    let text = SearchBar.text
    let url = NSURL(string: text!)
    let request:URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url! as URL)

    //let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url! as URL)

    Webview.loadRequest(request)

}

}
```

Comment: Also please note that you are force unwrapping the searchbar.text and using it to create your url request. it will cause an exception if the url entered isn't valid.

Also UISearchBarDelegate protocol is what you need to conform to, in order to know when the entered text is changed, you can then use this method to use the desired search text to create a url request.

Answer (score 0):

Add `UISearchBarDelegate` protocol methods to fire a search bar protocol method;

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UIWebViewDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        SearchBar.delegate = self
        webview.delegate = self // connect your webview in storyboard
    }

    // MARK: -  UISearchView Delegates
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchbar: UISearchBar) {
        // call your function here
               let searchText = searchbar.text!
               let url = URL (string: searchText)
               let requestObj = URLRequest(url: url!)
               webView.loadRequest(requestObj)

        }

}
```

Comment: do i make any change to func search bar? or leave it

Comment: add the same code inside your searchButtonClicked action

Comment: I hope now it trigger searchBarSearchButtonClicked function, when you enter the search button(from keyboard).